# Can't add "well" class to devise sign up form (form_for) using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, twitter-bootstrap

Why doesn't the "well" class get displayed when the page is rendered?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="offset4 span4">
      <h2>Sign up</h2>

      <%= form_for(resource, :html => { :class => "well" }, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
        <%= devise_error_messages! %>

        <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

        <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

        <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

        <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
      <% end %>

      <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The form looks like this when rendered:

```
    <form method="post" id="new_user" class="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"><input type="hidden" value="P3KHtU5CRNy0/kVEvck4coilSOWCHYaKPZ5D1xCxQj4=" name="authenticity_token"></div>


        <div><label for="user_email">Email</label><br>
        <input type="email" value="" size="30" name="user[email]" id="user_email"></div>

        <div><label for="user_password">Password</label><br>
        <input type="password" size="30" name="user[password]" id="user_password"></div>

        <div><label for="user_password_confirmation">Password confirmation</label><br>
        <input type="password" size="30" name="user[password_confirmation]" id="user_password_confirmation"></div>

        <div><input type="submit" value="Sign up" name="commit"></div>
</form>
```

Notice class is just "new_user". No "well", why and how do I fix it?

Thanks

UPDATE:

I've updated it to:

```
  <%= form_for(resource, :class => "well", :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="new_user" class="new_user" action="/users" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"><input type="hidden" value="P3KHtU5CRNy0/kVEvck4coilSOWCHYaKPZ5D1xCxQj4=" name="authenticity_token"></div>
```

Still not working.
Using Rails 3.2.8
Using HAML in the rest of the app even though these files are ERB. Could that be it?

Comment: Wrapping the html elements to your form in an `html` hash was valid in Rails 2.3, but not in 3+ --- so saverio is right on

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I've tried with :html and just plain :class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem was the inability to modify the views. It wasn't just limited to the class which I declared in the form_for correctly.
Correct answer:
[Customizing Devise views in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646845/customizing-devise-views-in-rails)
It's the answer with the higher votes.

I couldn't modify the views because I ran

```
rails generate devise:views User
```

It should have been

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Notice no mention of User.

Answer (score 16):

Actually the reason why your form_for doesn't append the class is because with form_for, you need to state it inside a :html hash:

```
form_for(resource, :html => {:class => "well"}, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do
```

[api.rubyonrails.org form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for), read the paragraph describing the three hash options (:url, :namespace and :html)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else having this problem, Speed's solution worked for me.

I decided to share my working solution's code. To get my app to look like http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/signin.html

I modified my /views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb to look like:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :html => {class:"form-signin"}, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<h2 class:"form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
<%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true, class:"input-block-level", placeholder:"Email address" %>
<%= f.password_field :password, class:"input-block-level", placeholder:"Password"%>

<% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%> 
    <label class="checkbox">
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> Remember Me
    </label>
<% end -%>

<%= f.submit "Sign in", class:"btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

<hr>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %><% end %>
```

Don't forget to add the css from the bootstrap example's head to your /assets/css Note that [type="email"] is used instead of [type="text"] as in the bootstrap example.

```
.form-signin {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 19px 29px 29px;
    margin: 40px auto 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

.form-signin .form-signin-heading,
.form-signin .checkbox {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-signin input[type="email"],
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 7px 9px;
}
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for(resource, :class => "well", :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Changing to :class => "well" didn't fix it for me. Could it be that this file is ERB while the rest of my app uses HAML?

Comment: I wrote it out of memory, but reading the docs it's wrong, the correct way is what you did the first time.

Comment: yeah, so i'm not understanding why it's not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: can't assign "class" like this, needs to go inside an HTML block, see speed's answer

Answer (score 0):

The way to apply custom styles (with Devise 3.5.3 and when you have more than one Devise model) is to enable scoped views in `config/initializers/devise.rb`.

It defaults to false. Change it to:

> config.scoped_views = true