# Rails devise generate Views for User Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

We are using devise for our rails application. I have run the following commands to install and generate devise into the app.

```
rails generate devise:install

rails generate devise user
```

Now I want to generate the views for the `User` model at `app/views/users/` instead of `app/views/devise`

Comment: devise maps all its views to devise directory, leaving rails' convention onto the developer to follow. Here you'd need to create a users controller and inherit from devise controller to override that behavior.

Comment: when you run `rails generate devise:install` you will have a message how to generate custom views

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14917262/2231236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rails generate devise:views users
```